# Apply a command to each occurrence of a pattern in a range

Tags: search, mark

I have `'a` and `'b` bounding some lines of text.  I want to convert all the `w`, `h`, `n`, and `m` variables to upper case.  A sample line:

```
f(w,h,n,m) | w <= 0 | h <= 0 | n < 0 | m < 0 = 0
```

It seems to me that this should work:

```
:'a,'b g/\<[whnm]\>/normal ~
```

This doesn't work.  It matches the line, but does not match the individual variables.  It leaves the cursor at the beginning of the line and capitalizes the `f` there.  How do I make it perform the `~` action at every match in the range?

I know this particular example can be done simply with a regex substitution.  I don't want to do that.  I want to run an arbitrary command at every location that matches a search pattern, which seems like something obvious to do, but so far appears impossible to do in vim.

Comment: Your problem is `:global` operates on entire lines only, and not the matching part. So you're running `~` for every line (which should convert the first character, `f`, to `F`). No time to write a more expanded answer right now, but at least you know your problem ;-)

Comment: To me, it seems like vim's problem instead of my problem.  I've been using vim exclusively for a couple of years, and have recently begun to try to step up my vim sophistication level.  I keep bumping into this butterfly every once in a while, and I'd like to kill it and pin it to the page.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
:'a,'b s/\v(<[whnm]>)/\U\1/g
```

Short expl.:

`\v` - very magic

`(...)` - create 1st group

`\U\1` - make 1st group uppercase

Good references: [vimregex](http://vimregex.com/), [W.A.Zintz'](http://dahu.github.io/vim_waz_ere/)s articles

---

To operate *on each match*, repeatedly, using a "normal-mode" command, you could do this instead:

```
/\C\v<[whnm]> ENTER
~       (<- or any other command(s) operating on the match)
qqn.q   (<- create a macro with "go to next result, repeat command(s) above")
20@q    (<- repeat the macro 20 times)
```

You can use any number instead of 20, ideally bigger than than the number of matches, the condition being that your command applied to the match makes it a non-match for a second search round - when the search hits bottom and starts again from the top (hence the `\C` - case sensitive search).

Comment: Yes, but I would like to perform an arbitrary command at every match.

Comment: The simplest would be to perform a search `\v<[whnm]>`, press `~` (or whatever command), and then it is just a matter of hitting `n.` repeatedly (and that could be automated).

Comment: Forgo the capture group as we can use `\0`/`&`. e.g. `:'a,'bs/\<[whnm]\>/\U&/g`.

Comment: @Peter Rincker - Yes, that's even nicer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the the `gn` motion to operation on the current search pattern match and repeat your operation via the `.` command. Example:

- `/foo` - set pattern
- `gUgn` - uppercase (`gU`) the current match, `gn`
- `n` move to the next match
- `.` to repeat your last operation, `gUgn`

Note: I find this method doesn't work the best with single character matches as `gn` will select the current charter to the next match.

You will need Vim 7.4 to use `gn` motion and 7.4.110+ to use `gUgn`.

For more help see:

```
:h gn
:h gU
```

There is also a nice [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode on this: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)

Comment: Actually, after `gUgn`, you just need `.`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macro that operates on the pattern you want and run it like 500 times. For instance I had a bunch of lines like this one:

`Vrvirksomhed.virksomhedMetadata.nyesteNavn.navn`

That I wanted to CamelCase, so i wrote this small macro: `/\.xvU`, and ran it until no more changes.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Another possible way to write your macro is to first do your search `/\.` and then use `n` in the macro, potentially that allows you to correct your search pattern on the fly without having to record the macro again.